# Android AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask() and deprecated onActivityResult() method

Tags: android, resolve, google-pay

I have a code:

```
                AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(gPay!!.loadPaymentData(request), this, 101)
```

The problem is that the last argument is a request code. And after that the onActivityResult() method is called. But it is deprecated. And how to change the code to "registerActivityForResult()" (to avoid onActivityResult())?